# How do you retrieve data from a db with PHP and MySQL and indent returned results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Just to put this program in perspective, Im trying to create a mini Bulletin.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE Postings
(
`PostID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`PostDate` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
`PostedBy` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`PostSubject` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`Content` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`ParentPost` INT( 11 ) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `PostID` )
)
```

And here is the data in that table:

```
insert into postings values  
        ('1','11/01/03 10:15','a@abc.com','Welcome','Welcome to the bulletin   board',NULL);
insert into postings values  
        ('2','12/01/03 08:00','b@abc.com','Welcome 2','This is posting 2','1');
insert into postings values  
        ('3','13/01/03 09:00','c@abc.com','Welcome 3','This is posting 3','1');
insert into postings values  
        ('4','14/01/03 10:15','a@abc.com','New Topic','This is posting 4',NULL);
insert into postings values  
        ('5','15/01/03 10:15','a@abc.com','New Topic 2','This is posting 5','4');
insert into postings values  
        ('6','16/01/03 10:15','a@abc.com','New Topic 3','This is posting 6','4');
insert into postings values  
        ('7','17/01/03 10:15','c@abc.com','Welcome 4','This is posting 7','2');
insert into postings values  
        ('8','18/01/03 10:15','d@abc.com','Welcome 5','This is posting 8','2');
insert into postings values  
        ('9','19/01/03 10:15','a@abc.com','Welcome 6','This is posting 9','8');
insert into postings values  
        ('10','20/01/03 10:15','b@abc.com','New Topic 4','This is posting 10','6');
```

PostID is auto increment and is Primary Key, ParentPost is also INT, and will have values assigned to it.

Now what I want to do is write a SQL statement and PHP code that will allow me to retrive all of the values from the DB, but indent every row that has a ParentPost value thats equal to a PostID value beneath the PostID row.

I have a pic at the bottom that could better explain what Im after.

This is what I have come up with so far with no luck:

```
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "OnlineBulletinBoardDB";

@mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("Could no connect to    MySQL");
@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("No database");

$query="SELECT PostSubject FROM postings GROUP BY PostID = ParentPost;";

$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();

?>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$dno=mysql_result($result,$i,"PostSubject");
?>

<?php echo $dno; ?><br/>

<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

The end result im looking for is this shown in the pic below:[image]

Cheers guys.

Comment: What is not working / what is the error?

Comment: The code above only retrieves "Welcome" and "Welcome 2". But I need to somehow retrieve all of the results, and display them in the format shown in the picture above.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is the key. To avoid doing lots of queries like "select * from Postings where ParentID = 0", "select * from Postings where ParentID = 1" etc do one query "select * from Postings" which brings back everything then populate a two dimension array with the parent id the key for the first array. The example below is untested but it should work with a bit of tidying up:

```
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "OnlineBulletinBoardDB";

@mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("Could no connect to    MySQL");
@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("No database");

$query="SELECT PostSubject, PostID, ParentID FROM postings";

$res = mysql_query($query);


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res){
    $parentID = intval($row['ParentID']);
    $posts[$parentID][] = $row;
}

function displayPosts($parentId, $posts){
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($posts[$parentId] as $post){
       echo "<li>";
           echo $post['PostSubject'];
           if(isset($posts[$post['PostID']])){
               displayPosts($post['PostID'],$posts);
           }
       echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

displayPosts($posts['PostID'],$posts);
```

Comment: If you want to fetch all entrys (as @Jason requested it), this is probably the best way. But be aware that this will kill your database performance very quickly :) More advanced: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Comment: @Fge I understand your point, but the bottleneck actually becomes php - this code only uses a straight forward SQL query. I think running out of memory will be the first issue you will hit.

Comment: @Xaerxess I had not noticed the NULL's in the db I have updated my code, @Jason I suggest you use NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 for your ParentID, NULL's require extra storage and can be awkward to deal with

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I can't edit [ejrowley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137943/how-do-you-retrieve-data-from-a-db-with-php-and-mysql-and-indent-returned-results/6139426#6139426) (I'm new to StackOverflow), so I post tidier and working example with recursion:

```php
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "OnlineBulletinBoardDB";

@mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("Could no connect to MySQL");
@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("No database");

$posts = array();
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM postings;");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $parentId = $row['ParentPost'];
    $posts[$parentId ? $parentId : 0][] = $row; // because you use NULL and array can't have NULL key                                        
}

function displayPosts($parentId, $posts) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($posts[$parentId] as $post) {
       echo "<li>";
           echo $post['PostSubject'];
           $postId = $post['PostID'];
           if (isset($posts[$postId])) {
               displayPosts($postId, $posts);
           }
       echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

displayPosts(0, $posts); // where 0 means 'no parent'                                                                                        

?>
```